# Math behind some quaternion code and gimbal lock

Tags: matlab, matrix, quaternions, gyroscope, euler-angles

I have the following matlab code that gives a Rotation matrix from Quaternion. The person who did this said he used some library and it is originally from this Rotation Matrix 
[image: Rotation Matrix from Quaternion]

The Rotation matrix according to the code looks like

[image: Rot Matrix according to code]

The diagonal elements and the signs are changed. Can someonw explain to me the math or the conditions for the disparity between the two.

```
Q0 = Quat(1);
Q1 = Quat(2);
Q2 = Quat(3);
Q3 = Quat(4);

%% set f2q to 2*q0 and calculate products
f2q = 2 * Q0;
f2q0q0 = f2q * Q0;
f2q0q1 = f2q * Q1;
f2q0q2 = f2q * Q2;
f2q0q3 = f2q * Q3;

 %% set f2q to 2*q1 and calculate products
 f2q = 2 * Q1;
 f2q1q1 = f2q * Q1;
 f2q1q2 = f2q * Q2;
 f2q1q3 = f2q * Q3;

 %% set f2q to 2*q2 and calculate products
 f2q = 2 * Q2;
 f2q2q2 = f2q * Q2;
 f2q2q3 = f2q * Q3;
 f2q3q3 = 2 * Q3 * Q3;

 %% calculate the rotation matrix assuming the quaternion is normalized
 R(1, 1) = f2q0q0 + f2q1q1 - 1;
 R(1, 2) = f2q1q2 + f2q0q3;
 R(1, 3) = f2q1q3 - f2q0q2;
 R(2, 1) = f2q1q2 - f2q0q3;
 R(2, 2) = f2q0q0 + f2q2q2 - 1;
 R(2, 3) = f2q2q3 + f2q0q1;
 R(3, 1) = f2q1q3 + f2q0q2;
 R(3, 2) = f2q2q3 - f2q0q1;
 R(3, 3) = f2q0q0 + f2q3q3 - 1;
```

Also...

The Rotation Matrix is used to find Euler Angles that also deals with Gimbal lock

```
 %%calculate the pitch angle -90.0 <= Theta <= 90.0 deg
        pitchdeg = asin(-R(1, 3)) * (180 / pi);

        %% calculate the roll angle range -180.0 <= Phi < 180.0 deg
        rolldeg = atan2(R(2, 3), R(3, 3)) * (180 / pi);

        %% map +180 roll onto the functionally equivalent -180 deg roll
        if (rolldeg == 180)

            rolldeg = -180;
        end

        %% calculate the yaw (compass) angle 0.0 <= Psi < 360.0 deg
        if (pitchdeg == 90)

            %% vertical upwards gimbal lock case
            yawdeg = (atan2(R(3, 2), R(2, 2)) * (180 / pi)) + rolldeg;
        elseif (pitchdeg == -90)

            %% vertical downwards gimbal lock case
            yawdeg = (Math.Atan2(-R(3, 2), R(2, 2)) * (180 / pi)) - rolldeg;

        else

            %% general case
            yawdeg = atan2(R(1, 2), R(1, 1)) * (180 / pi);
        end

        %% map yaw angle Psi onto range 0.0 <= Psi < 360.0 deg
        if (yawdeg < 0)

            yawdeg = yawdeg + 360;
        end

        %% check for rounding errors mapping small negative angle to 360 deg
        if (yawdeg >= 360)

            yawdeg = 0;
        end

        Euler.Roll = rolldeg;
        Euler.Pitch = pitchdeg;
        Euler.Yaw = yawdeg;
```

Googling the formula to convert from Quaternion to Euler angles gave me a formula which i could not attach because i dont have enough reputation but you can find it in wiki Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

The terms are different comparing with the diagonal of Rotation matrix. Also, is there a math behind the compensation for gimbal lock?

The IMU uses North-East-Down system

I am using euler angles to visualize the gyro. Any kind of guidance is appreciable

Comment: Yes there is math behind it. No this is not the place to ask for maths tutoring.

Comment: Note, f2q = 2 * Q0; produce NONunit quaternion and all its products is NONunit, so if you apply the conversion to matrix assuming its unit, it fails.